# Is there any way for an intelligent item to gain experience without someone giving up theirs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-advancement, intelligent-magic-items

I am planning to play as an intelligent item character but according to the rules an intelligent item needs experience infusion to be able to level up. Are there any alternative rules or feats that can allow an item to level up without experience infusion?

Comment: I'm not clear how you plan to play as an intelligent item character. What rules are you using for that?

Comment: Are you using the regular rules for playing as an intelligent item, or are you using 3rd party or 2nd party material?  When you say levelling up, do you mean getting class levels or more magic powers?

Comment: Look, it's really hard to answer you. Almost always you'll need to fall into custom rules when you come up with something wild. Intelligent items CAN be somewhat complex if the DM wants it. Some sentient weapons like Khazid'hea will literally gain strength from killing enemies. You can take that as an interpretation for exp and growth, but it did not gain levels, rather weapon stats. How exactly will your weapon character work? Think about that more than anything, because it needs to be plausible. How do you move, speak? Are you a trapped soul, and the soul instead gains levels? Why this idea?

Answer (score -4):

Just let the bearer of the item mirror experience they receive onto the item. Divide the experience between players as you normally would and essentially allow bonus experience equal to the bearer's received experience for the item. At least that's what I would do. I don't know about any rules or feats for it, but I personally would just make a house rule for it.

Comment: How well has this, or a similar rule, worked out for you in the past?

Comment: Hi Amaya, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Please note that [we expect homebrew answers to be backed up with experience of how they've worked out at the table](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5154/1204). It's pretty easy to come up with house rules, but experience tells us whether they're workable or not. In this case the asker is looking for extant in-game solutions, and we can usually take house rules as an option that's a given.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind in the future. I am new here and pretty new to DMing.